# Basic Use of openFDA Animal & Veterinary API

Tags: api, openfda

Will FDA be offering any additional training materials regarding use of its recently introduced openFDA Animal & Veterinary API?  Although I've read the 'How to use the API' instructions, the system is not intuitive.  No matter how I try to build a query to search the veterinary drug adverse event database, I encounter error messages such as:

```
{
"error": {
  "code": "NOT_FOUND",
  "message": "No matches found!"
  }
}
```

Comment: *No matter how I try to build a query*  Show your queries please. Because basically your question is "Why does my query not work?" - "Whether they will offer more training materials" is not likely something users of this website will know.

Answer (score 2):

I'm Jack with the openFDA Team. We've included extensive documentation on the website, but if you have specific questions (including example queries you've attempted just like @JanDoggen mentioned), I'd be happy to address those specifics. Otherwise check out the documentation linked below.

An example query from this endpoint: https://open.fda.gov/apis/animalandveterinary/event/example-api-queries/

The interactive chart show you what query it runs based on selected options: https://open.fda.gov/apis/animalandveterinary/event/explore-the-api-with-an-interactive-chart/

https://open.fda.gov/apis/query-parameters/ and the other pages under "Construct the Query" will teach you the syntax you'll need to build queries.

You can also just download the dataset if you need large chunks of data, but querying the API suits most needs.

Let me know if this helps or if you have any other questions.